# CG.Collect doesn't work in my big app, but works fine in a small project

Tags: c#, memory, garbage

When I put this code in a small Console project:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Mémoire avant allocation 1G: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");

byte[] buf = new byte[1000000000];

Console.WriteLine($"Mémoire après allocation 1G: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");

buf = null;

GC.Collect();

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

GC.Collect();

Console.WriteLine($"Mémoire après libération 1G: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");
```

I get the Following result (as expected):

> ```
>   Mémoire avant allocation 1G: 30028
>
>   Mémoire après allocation 1G: 1000038252
>
>   Mémoire après libération 1G: 29472
> ```

Now the very same code in the big Application I'm working on, I get this result:

> ```
> Mémoire avant allocation 1G: 153152496
>
> Mémoire après allocation 1G: 1153152552
>
> Mémoire après libération 1G: 1146813960
> ```

As you can see, `GC.Collect` does nothing here.

Why is that?

Comment: As I know Garbage Collector can modify conditions when and how to check and free unused objects on the fly by collecting information on how a certain program consumes memory. In a case when you create a lot of big objects the GC strategy can differ from the first described case.

Comment: Is the "big application" running on a server OS? Garbage collection behaves very differently on server OS's. Also, GC.Collect starts the garbage collection process, there are no guarantees what will be garbage collected. On "client" OS's like Windows 7/10 it's more aggressive, on server OS's at allows more memory usage because garbage collection is a performance intensive process. Furthermore, you're creating large byte arrays which will go straight to the large object heap (LOB), which, on server OS's, are not garbage collected often.

Comment: Addendum: LOB=LOH, and it's not separate but goes directly to gen2. Interesting stuff: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap

Comment: For both cases, the PC is the same (Win10 with lot of RAM available - 64Go total - no memory stress in both cases). The "big" app is just an app developped over a long period of time (10 yrs or so) with several teams working on it, so I'm not fluent with all aspects of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try compacting the LOH

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect( );
```

Also note that the documentation describing `GC.Collect( )` always uses the word "tries" or "try".

Example (emphasis mine):

> Use this method to ***try*** to reclaim all memory that is inaccessible. It performs a blocking garbage collection of all generations.
>
> All objects, regardless of how long they have been in memory, are considered for collection; however, objects that are referenced in managed code are not collected. Use this method to force the system to ***try*** to reclaim the maximum amount of available memory.

Comment: Your suggestion works: when adding
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
then the next GC.Collect do reclaim the 1G buffer just allocated. 

I understand that GC.Collect only tries to reclaim the memory, so if in both cases it wouldn't, I would easier accept it (as I have lot of memory, the application do not need more). Just what is unclear is why it behaves differently from the simple sample that was just before. 

Thank you for your help.